# Write 1 line If statement using ternary operator in JAVa

Tags: java, conditional-operator

Not sure its possible or not. I want to write 1 line if condition statement using ternary operator. Here is my code :

```
if(preconditionflag.equals("skip")){
System.out.println("Skipping this testcase due to earlier testcase failed");
return flag = "skip";
} else {
flag = "pass";
}
```

precondflag and flag are String paramaters. Also "else" part is optional to write so please provide code either with else part (flag = "pass") or without it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Not sure its possible or not.* It's possible.

Comment: this: ***precondflag == "skip"*** never ever in java

Comment: `if` case in your example contains `return` keyword which moves control flow to place from which method was invoked. Ternary operator can't do that. It just based on condition gives back one of two values specified by you. I am not sure what you are trying to do here and unclear questions tend to get down-votes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume your actual code looks like this:

```
if (preconditionflag.equals("skip")){
    System.out.println("Skipping this testcase due to earlier testcase failed");
    flag = "skip";
} else {
    flag = "pass";
}
```

If not, the answer to your question is already no, because you can't return from a method in one part and not return from a method in the other part of the ternary operation.

The other obstacle speaking against a ternary operation here is the output on STDOUT. Ternary operators don't allow that, but if you really need to you can solve it by creating a helper method:

```
private void myMethod() {
    ...
    flag = preconditionflag.equals("skip") ?
           showMessageAndReturn("Skipping this testcase due to earlier testcase failed", "skip") :
           "pass";
    ...
}

private String showMessageAndReturn(String message, String retVal) {
    System.out.println(message);
    return retVal;
}
```

This is an answer following your question exactly but I have difficulties to see an actual use for it in real life.

Comment: Thanks. Let me explain real use. The preconditionflag becomes "skip" when either test application becomes either logged out or unstable and keep loading until timeout. So when preconditionflag becomes "skip", I want to assign flag as "skip" and call return to skip remaining steps from execution.Later the flag status "skip" will be used to write back the result in Excel. Your answer is very closed to my need. Thank You.